# Prove that $G$ abelian if $|G|= pq^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $pq^2$, where $p \neq q$ prime and $p$ does not divide $| Aut (G) |$. Show that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: If this is homework, have you at least tried something? Can you show some work? Note that this is proved in some algebra books exercises ; I know that in Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra, there's a sketch of proof in the exercises.

Comment: It would be nice if you didn't phrase your question as a command, if you told us what you know about the problem, what theorems you are aware of that might be relevant, what work you have put into it yourself, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Isn't it important to know that $p$>$q$ or $q$>$p$ in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,we can consider a homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow Aut(G)$ such that:
$f(x)=t_x$,where $t_x:G\rightarrow G$ is defined by $t_x(g)=xgx^{-1}$.

Note that $ker f=Z(G)$,then by first isomorphism theorm, we get:
$G/Z(G)\cong f(G) \le Aut(G)$.So $|G| $can be divided by $|Z(G)||Aut(G)|$.

Hence, $Z(G)$ is divided by $p$.By Cauchy Theorem,$Z(G)$ contains a element of order $p$.
We find that the cyclic subgroup generated by that element is of order $p$ and hence is Sylow $p$ subgroup and since it is in the center, we can conclude that it is the unique Sylow $p$ subgroup,which is also normal.

Let $Q$ be a Sylow $q$ subgroup in $G$.Since $p$ and $q$ are relative prime,we have $P\cap Q=\{1\}$.Besides, $PQ$ is a subgroup of order $pq^2$ since $P$ is normal and $|PQ|=|P||Q|/|P\cap Q|$.We have $PQ=G$.

Now, we only focus on $Q$.From class equation ,we get that $Z(Q)$ is nontrivial.If $Z(Q)$ is of order $q^2$,then $Q$ commutes with its elements, otherwise $|Z(Q)|=q$.
In this case,$Q/Z(Q)$ which is of order $q$ and hence is cyclic, so $Q$ is abelian.
In both case, $Q$ always commutes with its elements.

Since $G=PQ$,$P$ is contained in the centre and $Q$ commutes with its elements,we can conclude that $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have that reference noted by Patrick, but I think you can use the following hint.

**Hint:** Use the fact that $|\frac{G}{Z(G)}|$ divides the order of $Aut(G)$.

Comment: So $|G/Z(G)|$ is not divisible by p which implies $|Z(G)|$ is $p, pq$ or $pq^2$, the case $Z(G)=pq$ is ruled out as otherwise  $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic and thus $Z(G)=G$. It remains to rule out the case $Z(G)=p$ ?

Comment: @user31899: If $Z(G)=p$ then $G≅Z(G)×\mathbb Z_{q^2}$?

Comment: Good work, nice hint! +1